# Why only the last item is inserted into database when adding multiple items?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to add multiple child records into the database,but only the last item gets inserted into the database.

**Model**

```
public string[] CourseID { get; set; }
public SelectList CourseList { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
StudentWalkInn _studentWalkInn = new StudentWalkInn();
....
....
//CourseId is of type string[]
if (mdlWalkInn.CourseID.Length > 0)
{
   StudentWalkInnCourse _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse();
   foreach (var courseId in mdlWalkInn.CourseID)
   {
       _studentCourse.CourseID=Convert.ToInt32(courseId);
       _studentWalkInn.StudentWalkInnCourses.Add(_studentCourse);
   }
}

_db.StudentWalkInns.Add(_studentWalkInn);
int i = _db.SaveChanges();
if (i > 0)
{
       //success message
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `mdlWalkInn.CourseID`?

Comment: The code that you provide is not complete. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No need to put tags in your title. They are already in your tags, which is good enough.

Comment: As a guess, you should move `StudentWalkInnCourse _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse();` inside the loop.

Comment: @YacoubMassad  updated the question

Comment: Why is `CourseID` a `string[]`? What do you expect will be saved to the database?

Comment: Course is a muliple select dropdownlist , where the user can select multiple items from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why only the last item is added is that you keep adding the same instance. When you change the ID in the loop, LINQ2SQL interprets it as a change of ID, not as an addition of a new item.

Adding different instances in each iteration of the loop should fix this problem:

```
foreach (var courseId in mdlWalkInn.CourseID)
{
    var _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse {
        CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(courseId)
    };
    _studentWalkInn.StudentWalkInnCourses.Add(_studentCourse);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same `StudentWalkInnCourse` object. Even if you add it multiple times, EF will detect that it is the same object and will not add a new entity.

Move the following line inside the loop.

```
StudentWalkInnCourse _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse();
```

Here is how the loop would look like:

```
foreach (var courseId in mdlWalkInn.CourseID)
{
    StudentWalkInnCourse _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse();
    _studentCourse.CourseID=Convert.ToInt32(courseId);
    _studentWalkInn.StudentWalkInnCourses.Add(_studentCourse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the new instance in the loop, because only setting a new id does not work.

```
if (mdlWalkInn.CourseID.Length > 0)
{
   foreach (var courseId in mdlWalkInn.CourseID)
   {
        StudentWalkInnCourse _studentCourse = new StudentWalkInnCourse();
       _studentCourse.CourseID=Convert.ToInt32(courseId);
       _studentWalkInn.StudentWalkInnCourses.Add(_studentCourse);
   }
}
```